# Does Firefox 70's Enhanced Tracking Protection obsolete certain extensions?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Now that Firefox 70 has [Enhanced Tracking Protection](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/70.0/releasenotes), are various major plugins obsolete?

I'm using these security-related extensions:

- Disconnect
- uBlock Origin
- Privacy Badger

Are they still necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good question, and one that I was curious about too.

The long answer is: not entirely. Mozilla tells us that the list of trackers that Firefox blocks comes from [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/trackerprotection), so in theory, the Disconnect extension is obsolete if you just want the protection without the fancy blocking statistics. Disconnect's website also provides the list of all domains it blocks and doesn't block, so if you want to know the precise details, there's nothing to stop you.

Other extensions like uBlock, Adblock Plus etc, either allow custom blocking and/or subscriptions to multiple block lists curated by different people, so you obviously get more control in those cases. Another kind of control that you get with these extensions that you cannot get with the vanilla browser is blocking/allowing specific domains per-site. Firefox's tracking protection is either on or off in its entirety. Case-in-point, I often find that I need to enable a few specific things that are blocked by default when I want to talk to an online support agent, since those services often double up as analytics services.

Comment: For disconnect - just so I'm clear - since firefox and disconnect use the same blocklists, the only extra I get from disconnect is that small popup with charts and things (which I never use anyway). Though I sometimes use the *"whitelist site"* option, and I see firefox doesn't have a similar option.

Comment: And uBO and friends blocks ads, something firefox just doesn't do.

Comment: Right, yep. Trackers and ads are two different beasts, and sometimes people want to treat them separately. As far as 'whitelisting' a site is concerned, you do get the ability to turn off Firefox tracking protection by clicking the half-shield icon next to the URL bar, so in theory, all your Disconnect needs are covered.

Comment: Well... kinda. If you do that then it disables tracking protection for all sites, on all tabs.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing on Firefox 71. The popup says tracking protection is on "for this site". Turning it on/off changes that for only the current domain. Other websites aren't affected.

Comment: Firefox 71.. I thought 70 was the latest?

Comment: Firefox Beta. ;)

Comment: Okay so I'll revisit this in a few months, and then ditch disconnect. Those sort of addons are always resource pigs! :)